# Caching `this.get("store").findAll("post")` result set

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

this route sends server request on every transition to the `post.index`. Including page reload, navigation and `link-to 'post.index'`.

I really need to load all the posts once, when that route is transitioned to the first time. What is the best way to cache the result set?

```
App.PostIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get("store").findAll("post")
  }
});
```

I am using Ember 1.0 and Ember Data 1.0.beta3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application route's model/setupController you can prefetch:

```
ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.store.find("post");
  }
});
```

And in your post index route you could do:

```
App.PostIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.all("post")
  }
});
```